# Slow animation for Expand and Collapse on tablet and smart phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am using UIWebView inside of my iOS application and in the webView I used Bootstrap UI for designing expand and collapse animation. The JavaScript framework that I used is ANgularJS. The issue that I faced is the slow animation for expand and collapse. You can easily reproduce this issue if you follow the steps bellow with your device (iPhone or iPad)

1- Opened the Bootstrap website (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)  by Safari with your iPad.

2- Under the collapse paragraph, tap on the sample button, which collapses and expands a simple content. Please notice the time that it takes to expand the content.

You can test this issue for JQuery as well, here are the steps:

1- opened JQuery Mobile website (http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/collapsibles/) by Safari with your iPad. 
2- tap on the sample button, which expands and collapses a simple button. Please notice the time that it takes to expand the content.

The time that it takes to do the expand and collapse is really slow based on our User Experience feedback. I researched about this issue and debugged the ANgularJS framework to see where does this issue come from. It seems that there is a method called EventHandler that causes this issue.

[image]

Anybody have any idea what are the other options for designing Expand and Collapse that works fast on device?

Comment: I would try removing some elements in the background from the dom do your animations then when you close the animation re-insert the elements you removed. That may smooth out your animation some.

Comment: The problem exists even with empty content, that's why I put Bootstrap and JQuery examples. Theses examples have no complex contents. Bootstrap has just one line of text as a content, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Speedy has suggested this because of doc reflows.  Rather than removing nodes, I would probably look to make your animations in a container absolutely positioned (if possible).  This should reduce or remove reflow overhead and theoretically improve animation.  Worth a test.

Comment: @MarkGraham I'm not sure if I understood your comment properly, would you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: @Hamid - The problem isn't with the one line that's being collapsed....it is the positioning of the child and parent nodes that are being re-calculated as your animations are taking place.

Comment: @Hamid - A container (div) that is positioned absolutely isn't in the 'flow' of the document, therefore animations occuring in said container, won't affect the geometry of child and parent nodes, so the browser won't need to repaint them.  Read about document reflow and repaint.

Comment: @MarkGraham - I did an experiment to see if it's the problem or not. I added only one button to the view with functionality of expand and collapse. I removed all other HTML code. But I still got the same issue.

Comment: @Hamid - Take a look at css3 for mobile animation.  Javascript animation isn't great.

Comment: @MarkGraham
It's a good idea, any sample code that you can recommend?
If yes, please post your suggestion as an answer then I can accept the answer.

Comment: @Hamid Fair enough but why would that make it slower with AngularJS than without? I recently converted an app to AngularJS and the jQuery accordion slowed down horrendously with the change.

Comment: @geoidesic The webkit on device is not as fast as the one we have on desktop for rendering JavaScript. AngularJS is using JQuery light so both of them have same response time. So it's better to use CSS for any kind of animation. I just added an answer for this question, I hope it would be useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this problem is using pure CSS for expand and collapse

HTML Code

```
<body>
    <section>
      <article>
        <details>
          <summary>Step by Step Guides</summary>
          <details>
            <summary>Getting Started</summary>
            <p>1. Signup for a free trial</p>
          </details>
          <details>
            <summary>Setting up a backup schedule</summary>
            <p>This step assumes you have already signed up and installed the software</p>
          </details>
        </details>
        <details>
          <summary>Installation/Upgrade Issues</summary>
          <p>After setup the program doesn't start</p>
        </details>
      </article>

      <article>
        <details>
          <summary>SERVER Step by Step Guides</summary>
          <details>
            <summary>Getting Started</summary>
            <p>1. Signup for a free trial</p>
          </details>
          <details>
            <summary>Setting up a backup schedule</summary>
            <p>This step assumes you have already signed up and installed the software</p>
          </details>
        </details>
        <details>
          <summary>Installation/Upgrade Issues</summary>
          <p>After setup the program doesn't start</p>
        </details>
      </article> 

</section>
</body>
```

CSS code

```
    summary::-webkit-details-marker {
 color: #00ACF3;
 font-size: 125%;
 margin-right: 2px;
}
summary:focus {
    outline-style: none;
}
article > details > summary {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 16px;
}
details > p {
    margin-left: 24px;
}
details details {
    margin-left: 36px;
}
details details summary {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Working code on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thurstanh/emtAm/2/)